# Remove all events from gnome-calendar

Tags: gnome-calendar

I want to remove all events from gnome-calendar and start from fresh. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to  `~/.local/share/evolution/calendar` and delete the data files there.

Comment: After **relogin** the events are gone. Thank you.

Comment: +1 @BobaFit, restart the gnome-shell service and alt-F2-->r are not enough.